# Invalid route in ASP.net MVC Core 2 app shows blank page

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have a new empty asp.net MVC Core 2 web app. When going to a non-existant route rather than coming with an error page it just shows a blank page.

The site is setup with IIS. I'm in Development environment. I've tried commenting `app.UserExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");` and `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` - I've tried them individually in my environment. None of it makes any difference, just blank pages returned.

Why aren't errors being returned when I enter an invalid route & how can I see them?

I also ran in debugging on the /Home/Error ActionMethod to see if it was being hit - it never was. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

short answer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.0

long answer:

the first line won't get hit on the debugger. 
there is another configuration you can for error codes specifically but needs a little more wiring up.

`app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/error/{0}");`

the target will be a 404.cshtml for a 404 not found. 401 etc. usually loaded from the shared folder, for example.

in your situation does error.cshtml exist in the home folder for the homecontroller? was the intent to have it for a SPA type app?

Comment: I'm just coming form the MVC 5 world, and trying to figure out how Core works prior to a greenfield build. So it's just a 'normal' MVC style server side web app. Are blank pages for non-existent routes by design? It's how templates are setup.

Comment: was it a a default setup core mvc setup?

Comment: Yes default. Here's an example, I'm setting up Elm (.core Elmah like package) - if users go to a non-existent route I want Elm to notify me - but it doesn't because there's no error raised.

Comment: Also - when the blank page is being returned from an invalid route - what code is being called? What is happening exactly?

Comment: I may have figured it out - lots of examples have this line in 'app.UseStatusCodePages();' in Configure - and it returns 404 (and I presume other status codes).